# What is the appropriate abstraction for a lens which can fail as a setter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I would like to define something like a lens, but which can fail when trying to set. See `fooLens` in the following example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Data.Functor.Const (Const(..))
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))

type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
type Getting r s t a = (a -> Const r a) -> s -> Const r t

view :: Getting a s t a -> s -> a
view l = getConst . l Const

over :: Lens s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> t
over l f = runIdentity . l (Identity . f)

data Foo a = Foo a deriving (Show)

fooLens :: Lens (Foo a) (Either String (Foo a)) a a
fooLens f (Foo a) = Right . Foo <$> f a

main = do
    let foo = Foo "test"
    print foo
    print $ view fooLens foo
    print $ over fooLens (map toUpper) foo
```

The output of this is what you would expect

```
Foo "test"
"test"
Right (Foo "TEST")
```

I have generalised the definition of `Getting` here to make this work. The first thing to make clear is that `fooLens` is not a lens: it doesn't satisfy the lens laws. Instead, it is the composition of a lens and something like a prism.

This seems to work, but the fact that it's not supported by any of the lens libraries I've checked suggests that there may be a better way to go about this problem. Is there a way to refactor `fooLens` so that it:

1. Acts as a getter, i.e. it can always retrieve a value.
2. Can act as a setter with the possibility of failing, for example it returns an Either.

Comment: The title of this question suggests a different question than the body asks. A `Prism` can fail when retrieving a value, but not when setting it. Are you looking for the opposite, an optic that can always retrieve a value but might sometimes fail to set it?

Comment: @Carl: Yes, that is what I want. However, I chose to be more succinct in the question title rather than ‘an unknown optic-like abstraction’. If you feel this is too misleading, I can change it, though I'm not sure what to.

Comment: Well, the numbered questions you asked ended up being about one specific way to achieve your goal, rather than about the best way to achieve your goal. You sort of XY-problemed yourself in the crafting of this question. If people focus only on the numbered questions you ask, they're unlikely to answer your real question.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I have rephrased my final questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific formulation doesn't work very well within the lens ecosystem. The most important thing lens does is provide composition of optics of different types. To demonstrate, let's start with a slightly embellished version of your code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Data.Functor.Const (Const(..))
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))

type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
type Getting r s t a = (a -> Const r a) -> s -> Const r t

view :: Getting a s t a -> s -> a
view l = getConst . l Const

over :: Lens s t a b -> (a -> b) -> s -> t
over l f = runIdentity . l (Identity . f)

data Foo a = Foo a
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

fooLens :: Lens (Foo [a]) (Either String (Foo [a])) [a] [a]
fooLens f (Foo a) = update <$> f a
  where
    update x | null x = Left "Cannot be empty"
             | otherwise = Right (Foo x)

main = do
    let foo = Foo "test"
    print foo
    print $ view fooLens foo
    print $ over fooLens (map toUpper) foo
    print $ over fooLens (const "") foo
```

The output is:

```
Foo "test"
"test"
Right (Foo "TEST")
Left "Cannot be empty"
```

I modified `fooLens` a bit to take full advantage of its type, validating data on update. This helps to illustrate the goal with this formulation.

Then I decided to test out how well this composes, and added the following:

```
data Bar = Bar (Foo String)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

barLens :: Lens Bar Bar (Foo String) (Foo String)
barLens f (Bar x) = Bar <$> f x
```

And then adding the following to `main`:

```
    print $ view (barLens . fooLens) (Bar foo)
```

It just doesn't compose:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Either String (Foo [Char])’
                     with ‘Foo String’
      Expected type: ([Char] -> Const [Char] [Char])
                     -> Foo String -> Const [Char] (Foo String)
        Actual type: ([Char] -> Const [Char] [Char])
                     -> Foo [Char] -> Const [Char] (Either String (Foo [Char]))
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘fooLens’
      In the first argument of ‘view’, namely ‘(barLens . fooLens)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘view (barLens . fooLens) (Bar foo)’
   |
37 |     print $ view (barLens . fooLens) (Bar foo)
   |                             ^^^^^^^
```

This alone is enough to prevent using this formulation in lens. It doesn't fit within the goals of the library.

Let's try something different. This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it's an observation.

```
import Control.Lens

data Foo a = Foo a
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

fooLens :: Lens (Foo [a]) (Foo [a]) [a] [a]
fooLens f (Foo a) = update <$> f a
  where
    update x | null x = Foo a
             | otherwise = Foo x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let foos = map Foo $ words "go fly a kite"
    print foos
    print $ toListOf (traverse . fooLens) foos
    print $ over (traverse . fooLens) tail foos
    print =<< (traverse . fooLens) (\x -> tail x <$ print x) foos
```

Output:

```
[Foo "go",Foo "fly",Foo "a",Foo "kite"]
["go","fly","a","kite"]
[Foo "o",Foo "ly",Foo "a",Foo "ite"]
"go"
"fly"
"a"
"kite"
[Foo "o",Foo "ly",Foo "a",Foo "ite"]
```

Obviously that's not a true lens and should probably have a different name, as it doesn't obey the set-view law. It's a bit awkward that it can be written with the same type, but there's precedent for that with things like `filtered`.

But there's a further complication, as evidenced by the last test - filtering on the result of an update still requires running the update's effects, even when the update is rejected. That's not how skipping an element, with `filtered` for instance, in a `Traversal` works. That seems like it's impossible to avoid with the van Laarhoven representation. But maybe that's not so bad. It isn't an issue when setting or viewing - only when doing much less common operations.

In any case, it doesn't report the failure to set, so it's not exactly what you're looking for. But with enough rejiggering, it can be a starting point.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
        MultiParamTypeClasses,
        FlexibleInstances,
        TypeFamilies,
        UndecidableInstances,
        FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

import Control.Lens



class Functor f => Reportable f e where
    report :: a -> f (Either e a) -> f a

instance Reportable (Const r) e where
    report _ (Const x) = Const x

instance Reportable Identity e where
    report a (Identity i) = Identity $ either (const a) id i

instance (e ~ a) => Reportable (Either a) e where
    report _ = join

overWithReport
    :: ((a -> Either e b) -> s -> Either e t)
    -> (a -> b)
    -> s
    -> Either e t
overWithReport l f s = l (pure . f) s



data Foo a = Foo a
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

fooLens
    :: (Reportable f String)
    => ([a] -> f [a])
    -> Foo [a]
    -> f (Foo [a])
fooLens f (Foo a) = report (Foo a) $ update <$> f a
  where
    update x | null x = Left "Cannot be empty"
             | otherwise = Right $ Foo x



main :: IO ()
main = do
    let foos = [Foo [1], Foo [2, 3]]
    print foos

    putStrLn "\n  Use as a normal lens:"
    print $ toListOf (traverse . fooLens . traverse) foos
    print $ over (traverse . fooLens . traverse) (+ 10) foos
    print $ over (traverse . fooLens) tail foos

    putStrLn "\n  Special use:"
    print $ overWithReport (traverse . fooLens . traverse) (+ 10) foos
    print $ overWithReport (traverse . fooLens) (0 :) foos
    print $ overWithReport (traverse . fooLens) tail foos
```

And here's the output from running it:

```
[Foo [1],Foo [2,3]]

  Use as a normal lens:
[1,2,3]
[Foo [11],Foo [12,13]]
[Foo [1],Foo [3]]

  Special use:
Right [Foo [11],Foo [12,13]]
Right [Foo [0,1],Foo [0,2,3]]
Left "Cannot be empty"
```

This formulation integrates with normal lens stuff. It works, at the expense of requiring a variation on `over` to get the error reporting. It maintains compatibility with a lot of lens functions, at the cost of a bit of non-lawful behavior in one case. It's not perfect, but it's probably as close as you can get within the constraints of maintaining compatibility with the rest of the lens library.

As for why something along these lines isn't in the library, it's probably because it requires a custom constraint on the `f` type alias, which is a real hassle for working with combinators like `(%%~)`. The instances I provided for `Identity` and `Const` take care of most uses from lens itself, but there's a more people might choose to do with it.

The lens library's open design allows for a huge amount of external customization. This is a possible approach that probably works for a lot of cases. But it works for a lot less than the full breadth of what lens allows, and I think that's why nothing like this is currently present.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because there's an unstated type-level law for profunctor optics.  A `s t a b` optic type needs to satisfy the type-level law:  `a ~ b` implies `s ~ t`.

As a result, `Getting` isn't generalized because its type has `a ~ b` which implies `s ~ t`.  Similarly, `fooLens` isn't a known optic because it violates this law, so it's kind of a non-starter.

As I say, I've never seen this type-level law made explicit, but I think it's implied.

Comment: It's stated slightly indirectly in http://comonad.com/reader/2012/mirrored-lenses/ , which the lens documentation still refers to. See the "Why is it a Lens Family?" section, and note that the pseudo-Haskell formulation it gives requires your type-level law to be true.

Comment: I think it's perfectly sensible to change phantoms on the side.

Comment: @Carl: That section seems to justify it by citing the lens laws. However, it's not clear why that must hold for other optics.

Comment: Well, I think it's clear why it needs to hold for equalities, isos, lenses, traversals, prisms, and setters, so that really just leaves getters and folds.  I guess it's not clear to me what extra generality a `Getting r s t a` really buys you.  I mean, why stop there?  Where's the optic that represents getting an `a` from an `s` while setting a `b` in a `t` to a `c` to get a `u`?  If there's no underlying semantic relationship between the types `s`, `t`, `a`, and `b`, why have optics at all?  Just use separate getters and setters and forget the rest.

Comment: I argue that in this case there is a semantic relationship between `s`, `t`, `a`, and `b`, and we do have something similar to the Prism laws which hold here.
`set l (view l b) ≡ Right b`
`set l s ≡ Right a` implies `view l a ≡ s`
I'm not sure what the analogue of `matching` is, but something can probably be defined.

Comment: optics-core defines a [ReversedPrism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-core-0.4/docs/Optics-ReversedPrism.html): it is basically `re` applied to a Prism, and is a superclass of a getter. I'm not sure of the laws precisely, but this looks promising.

Comment: @StephenMorgan I don't think `ReversedPrism` is a useful model for this. It acts only as a getter by itself - there's no facility for updating through one. The reason it exists is so that `re . re` gives you back a `Prism` when passed one.